# How to make div align center and overlap? when they are using same name

Tags: html, css

How to make div align center and overlap? when they are using same name
If I use position: absolute that means I have to set the left too and they can't be align center..

http://jsfiddle.net/pA8q4/

```
<div align="center" class="picwrap">pic
   <div class="pic">a</div>
   <div class="pic">b</div>
   <div class="pic">c</div>
</div>

.picwrap{
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 50px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 600px;
background-color: cyan;
}

.pic{
height: 70px;
width: 50px;
background-color: orange;
top: 0;     
}
```

Comment: please clarify what is wrong with the fiddle you posted, what do you want to be changed in it? please be descriptive..

Comment: i want to make 3 div .pic overlap in the same place(top: 0), and the place align center. i try to use top: 0 but i know it does't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append this style onto CSS:

```
.pic+.pic{
    position : relative;
    margin-top : -70px;
}
```

Comment: ... And a `margin: 0 auto;` on `.pic` to center it horizontally.

Comment: @user1575921: `+` means *next sibling*

Answer (score 1):

You will need `position: absolute;` on your `.pic` CSS for the `top: 0;` to work:

```
.pic{
    height: 70px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: if postion: absolute   have to set left: value too, and they are not in align center

Comment: @user1575921 - You're using explicit widths on everything, so you can set `left` based on that. In the JSFiddle example you posted, set `position: absolute`, like kevin suggested, and `left: 275px`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paFFD/).

Comment: you can center absolute position elements by setting left to 50% and margin-left to -137px (half of the element's width).

Answer (score 0):

If you want .pic to be centered inside your absolutely positioned div you should make the display method block and set the left and right margins to auto. like so:

```
.pic{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 0;     
}
```

If you want the .pic to be positioned at the top of the containing element than they need to also have absolute position as well as top set to 0.

Comment: i want to make center and overlap same row

Comment: can you be more specific, from what I understand you want them to be at the top and layered on top of each other, so it looks like there is only one image. Am I correct? Do you want them alongside each other and centered? Did you try display:inline?

Comment: they are from sql output, different image.